# Can not Receive

Tags: transactions, wallet

i am new here and i am new with BTC. 
Its the first time that i buy btc. 
So, i already buy the btc and than i install bitcoin core wallet.
After this i create a receivin no wallet and than the site had transfered the btc on this wallet adress.

But i dont receive?

What is the problem?

The Softwear shows : Synchronizing with the Netwerk : 2 years and 50 weeks in behindhand

Please can anybody help me!?!?!

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your wallet is still syncing. Don't worry. It should take a couple of days straight of syncing to complete, but then you should see the coins in your wallet. Your transaction exists in the bitcoin network, but your wallet just hasn't read over it yet. Don't worry.

If you want, you could use a wallet that doesn't require syncing, like [Electrum](http://electrum.org). Remember to go and save your wallet.dat file and transfer it to Electrum first, as this is your access file to your bitcoin. Lose that, lose your bitcoin. You should be able to import the wallet.dat into Electrum.